# Segmentation fault with tensorboard 1.14

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, segmentation-fault, tensorboard

I am using [deeplab network](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/cityscapes.md). I think it is using tensorflow 1.14 since there are still packages of slim, which is removed from tensorflow 2.0. The python version is always *Python 3.6.8* in my case.

I have sucessfullt run tensorboard from a venv(tensor2env) with

```
tensorboard                   2.0.1    
tensorflow                    2.0.0    
tensorflow-estimator          2.0.1
```

But when I want to visualize the same log from a venv(venv) with

```
tensorboard                        2.0.1      
tensorflow                         1.14.0     
tensorflow-estimator               1.14.0     
tensorflow-gpu                     1.14.0
```

it simply returns

```
(venv) zwang@mrt212:~/workspace/models-master/research/deeplab/datasets/cityscapes/exp/x65_city$ tensorboard --logdir=./
Segmentation fault
```

when I try that out in another venv(env) with the packages:

```
tensorboard                   1.14.0 
tensorflow                    1.14.0 
tensorflow-estimator          1.14.0
```

it also returns Segmentation fault, along with some "Future wornings"

```
/home/zwang/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
Segmentation fault
```

the debug info is so limited in my case, that it quite difficult for me to understand what is going wrong.

Does anyone have an idea of it?

---

the full lists of two venv are listed underneath:

## venv of tensorflow 1.14

```
Package                            Version    
---------------------------------- -----------
absl-py                            0.8.1      
actionlib                          1.12.0     
aenum                              2.2.1      
alabaster                          0.7.12     
angles                             1.9.11     
asn1crypto                         1.2.0      
astor                              0.8.0      
attrs                              19.3.0     
autobahn                           19.10.1    
Automat                            0.8.0      
Babel                              2.7.0      
backports.functools-lru-cache      1.5        
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size 1.0.0      
backports.weakref                  1.0.post1  
bcrypt                             3.1.7      
beautifulsoup4                     4.8.1      
blinker                            1.4        
bondpy                             1.8.3      
Brlapi                             0.6.6      
bzr                                2.8.0.dev1 
cachetools                         3.1.1      
camera-calibration                 1.13.0     
camera-calibration-parsers         1.11.13    
catkin                             0.7.19     
catkin-pkg                         0.4.14     
catkin-pkg-modules                 0.4.14     
catkin-tools                       0.4.5      
cbor                               1.0.0      
certifi                            2019.9.11  
cffi                               1.13.1     
chardet                            3.0.4      
cityscapesScripts                  1.1.0      
Click                              7.0        
cloudpickle                        1.2.2      
colorama                           0.4.1      
configglue                         1.1.3.post0
configobj                          5.0.6      
configparser                       4.0.2      
constantly                         15.1.0     
controller-manager                 0.15.1     
controller-manager-msgs            0.15.1     
coverage                           4.5.4      
cryptography                       2.8        
cv-bridge                          1.13.0     
cycler                             0.10.0     
Cython                             0.29.13    
decorator                          4.4.0      
defer                              1.0.6      
defusedxml                         0.6.0      
diagnostic-analysis                1.9.3      
diagnostic-common-diagnostics      1.9.3      
diagnostic-updater                 1.9.3      
dirspec                            13.10      
distlib                            0.2.9.post0
distro                             1.4.0      
docutils                           0.15.2     
duplicity                          0.7.17     
dynamic-reconfigure                1.6.0      
ecdsa                              0.13.3     
empy                               3.3.4      
entrypoints                        0.3        
enum34                             1.1.6      
fasteners                          0.15       
funcsigs                           1.0.2      
functools32                        3.2.3.post2
future                             0.18.1     
futures                            3.3.0      
gast                               0.2.2      
gazebo-plugins                     2.8.4      
gazebo-ros                         2.8.4      
gcovr                              4.1        
GDAL                               2.2.2      
gencpp                             0.6.2      
geneus                             2.2.6      
genlisp                            0.4.16     
genmsg                             0.5.12     
gennodejs                          2.0.1      
genpy                              0.6.9      
geodesy                            0.5.3      
google-auth                        1.7.0      
google-auth-oauthlib               0.4.1      
google-pasta                       0.1.7      
grpcio                             1.24.3     
h5py                               2.10.0     
html5lib                           1.0.1      
httplib2                           0.14.0     
hyperlink                          19.0.0     
idna                               2.8        
image-geometry                     1.13.0     
imagesize                          1.1.0      
incremental                        17.5.0     
iniparse                           0.4        
interactive-markers                1.11.4     
ipaddress                          1.0.23     
ipython                            5.8.0      
ipython-genutils                   0.2.0      
isodate                            0.6.0      
Jinja2                             2.10.3     
kdl-parser-py                      1.13.1     
Keras-Applications                 1.0.8      
Keras-Preprocessing                1.1.0      
keyring                            18.0.1     
keyrings.alt                       3.1.1      
kiwisolver                         1.1.0      
laser-geometry                     1.6.4      
launchpadlib                       1.10.7     
lazr.restfulclient                 0.14.2     
lazr.uri                           1.0.3      
lockfile                           0.12.2     
louis                              3.5.0      
lxml                               4.4.1      
lz4                                2.2.1      
Mako                               1.1.0      
Markdown                           3.1.1      
MarkupSafe                         1.1.1      
matplotlib                         2.2.4      
mercurial                          5.1.2      
message-filters                    1.14.3     
mock                               3.0.5      
monotonic                          1.5        
mpi4py                             3.0.2      
mrt                                0.1.3      
ndg-httpsclient                    0.5.1      
netifaces                          0.10.9     
networkx                           2.2        
nose                               1.3.7      
numpy                              1.16.5     
oauth                              1.0.1      
oauthlib                           3.1.0      
olefile                            0.46       
opt-einsum                         2.3.2      
osrf-pycommon                      0.1.8      
OWSLib                             0.18.0     
packaging                          19.2       
PAM                                0.4.2      
paramiko                           2.6.0      
pathlib2                           2.3.5      
pbr                                5.4.3      
pexpect                            4.7.0      
pickleshare                        0.7.5      
Pillow                             6.2.1      
pip                                19.3.1     
piston-mini-client                 0.7.5      
ply                                3.11       
prompt-toolkit                     2.0.10     
protobuf                           3.10.0     
psutil                             5.6.3      
psycopg2                           2.8.4      
ptyprocess                         0.6.0      
py-ubjson                          0.14.0     
pyasn1                             0.4.7      
pyasn1-modules                     0.2.7      
pycairo                            1.18.1     
pycparser                          2.19       
pycrypto                           2.6.1      
pycups                             1.9.73     
pycurl                             7.43.0.3   
pydot                              1.4.1      
Pygments                           2.4.2      
pygobject                          3.26.1     
pygraphviz                         1.5        
PyHamcrest                         1.9.0      
pyinotify                          0.9.6      
PyJWT                              1.7.1      
pykerberos                         1.2.1      
PyNaCl                             1.3.0      
PyOpenGL                           3.1.0      
pyOpenSSL                          19.0.0     
pyparsing                          2.4.2      
pyproj                             2.2.2      
pyserial                           3.4        
PySide                             1.2.4      
pysmbc                             1.0.15.6   
pyspatialite                       3.0.1      
python-apt                         1.6.4      
python-dateutil                    2.8.0      
python-debian                      0.1.36     
python-gnupg                       0.4.5      
python-qt-binding                  0.3.6      
python-snappy                      0.5.4      
PyTrie                             0.3.1      
pytz                               2019.3     
PyWavelets                         1.0.3      
pyxdg                              0.26       
PyYAML                             5.1.2      
qrcode                             6.1        
qt-dotgraph                        0.3.15     
qt-gui                             0.3.15     
qt-gui-cpp                         0.3.15     
qt-gui-py-common                   0.3.15     
rdflib                             4.2.2      
reportlab                          3.5.31     
requests                           2.22.0     
requests-oauthlib                  1.3.0      
resource-retriever                 1.12.5     
roman                              3.2        
rosbag                             1.14.3     
rosboost-cfg                       1.14.7     
rosclean                           1.14.7     
roscreate                          1.14.7     
rosdep                             0.17.1     
rosdistro                          0.7.5      
rosdistro-modules                  0.7.5      
rosgraph                           1.14.3     
rosinstall                         0.7.8      
rosinstall-generator               0.1.18     
roslaunch                          1.14.3     
roslib                             1.14.7     
roslint                            0.11.2     
roslz4                             1.14.3     
rosmake                            1.14.7     
rosmaster                          1.14.3     
rosmsg                             1.14.3     
rosnode                            1.14.3     
rosparam                           1.14.3     
rospkg                             1.1.10     
rospkg-modules                     1.1.10     
rospy                              1.14.3     
rosservice                         1.14.3     
rostest                            1.14.3     
rostopic                           1.14.3     
rosunit                            1.14.7     
roswtf                             1.14.3     
rqt-action                         0.4.9      
rqt-bag                            0.4.12     
rqt-bag-plugins                    0.4.12     
rqt-console                        0.4.8      
rqt-dep                            0.4.9      
rqt-graph                          0.4.10     
rqt-gui                            0.5.0      
rqt-gui-py                         0.5.0      
rqt-image-view                     0.4.13     
rqt-launch                         0.4.8      
rqt-logger-level                   0.4.8      
rqt-moveit                         0.5.7      
rqt-msg                            0.4.8      
rqt-nav-view                       0.5.7      
rqt-plot                           0.4.9      
rqt-pose-view                      0.5.8      
rqt-publisher                      0.4.8      
rqt-py-common                      0.5.0      
rqt-py-console                     0.4.8      
rqt-reconfigure                    0.5.0      
rqt-robot-dashboard                0.5.7      
rqt-robot-monitor                  0.5.9      
rqt-robot-steering                 0.5.9      
rqt-runtime-monitor                0.5.7      
rqt-rviz                           0.6.0      
rqt-service-caller                 0.4.8      
rqt-shell                          0.4.9      
rqt-srv                            0.4.8      
rqt-tf-tree                        0.6.0      
rqt-top                            0.4.8      
rqt-topic                          0.4.10     
rqt-web                            0.4.8      
rsa                                4.0        
rviz                               1.13.5     
scandir                            1.10.0     
scikit-image                       0.14.5     
scipy                              1.2.2      
scour                              0.37       
SecretStorage                      2.3.1      
sensor-msgs                        1.12.7     
service-identity                   18.1.0     
setuptools                         41.4.0     
Shapely                            1.6.4.post2
simplegeneric                      0.8.1      
simplejson                         3.16.0     
six                                1.12.0     
smach                              2.0.1      
smach-ros                          2.0.1      
smclib                             1.8.3      
snowballstemmer                    2.0.0      
software-center-aptd-plugins       0.0.0      
sortedcontainers                   2.1.0      
soupsieve                          1.9.4      
SPARQLWrapper                      1.8.4      
Sphinx                             1.8.5      
sphinx-rtd-theme                   0.4.3      
sphinxcontrib-websupport           1.1.2      
stevedore                          1.31.0     
subprocess32                       3.5.4      
svgwrite                           1.3.1      
tensorboard                        2.0.1      
tensorflow                         1.14.0     
tensorflow-estimator               1.14.0     
tensorflow-gpu                     1.14.0     
termcolor                          1.1.0      
testresources                      2.0.1      
tf                                 1.12.0     
tf-conversions                     1.12.0     
tf2-geometry-msgs                  0.6.5      
tf2-kdl                            0.6.5      
tf2-py                             0.6.5      
tf2-ros                            0.6.5      
tf2-sensor-msgs                    0.6.5      
topic-tools                        1.14.3     
tortoisehg                         4.5.2      
tqdm                               4.36.1     
traitlets                          4.3.3      
Tree                               0.2.4      
trollius                           2.2.post1  
Twisted                            19.7.0     
txaio                              18.8.1     
typing                             3.7.4.1    
u-msgpack-python                   2.5.2      
unique-id                          1.0.6      
unity-lens-photos                  1.0        
urdfdom-py                         0.4.1      
urllib3                            1.25.6     
vcstools                           0.1.42     
virtkey                            0.63.0     
virtualenv                         16.7.7     
virtualenv-clone                   0.5.3      
virtualenvwrapper                  4.8.4      
wadllib                            1.3.3      
wcwidth                            0.1.7      
webencodings                       0.5.1      
Werkzeug                           0.16.0     
wheel                              0.33.6     
wrapt                              1.11.2     
wsaccel                            0.6.2      
wsgi-intercept                     1.9.0      
wstool                             0.1.17     
wxPython                           4.0.6      
wxPython-common                    3.0.2.0    
xacro                              1.13.4     
xkit                               0.0.0      
zope.interface                     4.6.0
```

## tensor2env of tensorboard 2.0:

```
Package                       Version  
----------------------------- ---------
absl-py                       0.8.1    
actionlib                     1.12.0   
angles                        1.9.11   
astor                         0.8.0    
bondpy                        1.8.3    
cachetools                    3.1.1    
camera-calibration            1.13.0   
camera-calibration-parsers    1.11.13  
catkin                        0.7.19   
certifi                       2019.9.11
chardet                       3.0.4    
controller-manager            0.15.1   
controller-manager-msgs       0.15.1   
cv-bridge                     1.13.0   
diagnostic-analysis           1.9.3    
diagnostic-common-diagnostics 1.9.3    
diagnostic-updater            1.9.3    
dynamic-reconfigure           1.6.0    
gast                          0.2.2    
gazebo-plugins                2.8.4    
gazebo-ros                    2.8.4    
gencpp                        0.6.2    
geneus                        2.2.6    
genlisp                       0.4.16   
genmsg                        0.5.12   
gennodejs                     2.0.1    
genpy                         0.6.9    
geodesy                       0.5.3    
google-auth                   1.7.0    
google-auth-oauthlib          0.4.1    
google-pasta                  0.1.8    
grpcio                        1.25.0   
h5py                          2.10.0   
idna                          2.8      
image-geometry                1.13.0   
interactive-markers           1.11.4   
kdl-parser-py                 1.13.1   
Keras-Applications            1.0.8    
Keras-Preprocessing           1.1.0    
laser-geometry                1.6.4    
Markdown                      3.1.1    
message-filters               1.14.3   
numpy                         1.17.3   
oauthlib                      3.1.0    
opt-einsum                    3.1.0    
pip                           19.0.3   
protobuf                      3.10.0   
pyasn1                        0.4.7    
pyasn1-modules                0.2.7    
python-qt-binding             0.3.6    
qt-dotgraph                   0.3.15   
qt-gui                        0.3.15   
qt-gui-cpp                    0.3.15   
qt-gui-py-common              0.3.15   
requests                      2.22.0   
requests-oauthlib             1.3.0    
resource-retriever            1.12.5   
rosbag                        1.14.3   
rosboost-cfg                  1.14.7   
rosclean                      1.14.7   
roscreate                     1.14.7   
rosgraph                      1.14.3   
roslaunch                     1.14.3   
roslib                        1.14.7   
roslint                       0.11.2   
roslz4                        1.14.3   
rosmake                       1.14.7   
rosmaster                     1.14.3   
rosmsg                        1.14.3   
rosnode                       1.14.3   
rosparam                      1.14.3   
rospy                         1.14.3   
rosservice                    1.14.3   
rostest                       1.14.3   
rostopic                      1.14.3   
rosunit                       1.14.7   
roswtf                        1.14.3   
rqt-action                    0.4.9    
rqt-bag                       0.4.12   
rqt-bag-plugins               0.4.12   
rqt-console                   0.4.8    
rqt-dep                       0.4.9    
rqt-graph                     0.4.10   
rqt-gui                       0.5.0    
rqt-gui-py                    0.5.0    
rqt-image-view                0.4.13   
rqt-launch                    0.4.8    
rqt-logger-level              0.4.8    
rqt-moveit                    0.5.7    
rqt-msg                       0.4.8    
rqt-nav-view                  0.5.7    
rqt-plot                      0.4.9    
rqt-pose-view                 0.5.8    
rqt-publisher                 0.4.8    
rqt-py-common                 0.5.0    
rqt-py-console                0.4.8    
rqt-reconfigure               0.5.0    
rqt-robot-dashboard           0.5.7    
rqt-robot-monitor             0.5.9    
rqt-robot-steering            0.5.9    
rqt-runtime-monitor           0.5.7    
rqt-rviz                      0.6.0    
rqt-service-caller            0.4.8    
rqt-shell                     0.4.9    
rqt-srv                       0.4.8    
rqt-tf-tree                   0.6.0    
rqt-top                       0.4.8    
rqt-topic                     0.4.10   
rqt-web                       0.4.8    
rsa                           4.0      
rviz                          1.13.5   
sensor-msgs                   1.12.7   
setuptools                    41.6.0   
six                           1.13.0   
smach                         2.0.1    
smach-ros                     2.0.1    
smclib                        1.8.3    
tensorboard                   2.0.1    
tensorflow                    2.0.0    
tensorflow-estimator          2.0.1    
termcolor                     1.1.0    
tf                            1.12.0   
tf-conversions                1.12.0   
tf2-geometry-msgs             0.6.5    
tf2-kdl                       0.6.5    
tf2-py                        0.6.5    
tf2-ros                       0.6.5    
tf2-sensor-msgs               0.6.5    
topic-tools                   1.14.3   
unique-id                     1.0.6    
urdfdom-py                    0.4.1    
urllib3                       1.25.6   
Werkzeug                      0.16.0   
wheel                         0.33.6   
wrapt                         1.11.2   
xacro                         1.13.4
```

## the pip list of the thrid venv(env) with tensorflow 1.14, which don't have tensorflow-gpu

```
Package                       Version
----------------------------- -------
absl-py                       0.8.1  
actionlib                     1.12.0 
angles                        1.9.11 
astor                         0.8.0  
bondpy                        1.8.3  
camera-calibration            1.13.0 
camera-calibration-parsers    1.11.13
catkin                        0.7.19 
controller-manager            0.15.1 
controller-manager-msgs       0.15.1 
cv-bridge                     1.13.0 
cycler                        0.10.0 
diagnostic-analysis           1.9.3  
diagnostic-common-diagnostics 1.9.3  
diagnostic-updater            1.9.3  
dynamic-reconfigure           1.6.0  
gast                          0.3.2  
gazebo-plugins                2.8.4  
gazebo-ros                    2.8.4  
gencpp                        0.6.2  
geneus                        2.2.6  
genlisp                       0.4.16 
genmsg                        0.5.12 
gennodejs                     2.0.1  
genpy                         0.6.9  
geodesy                       0.5.3  
google-pasta                  0.1.8  
grpcio                        1.25.0 
h5py                          2.10.0 
image-geometry                1.13.0 
interactive-markers           1.11.4 
kdl-parser-py                 1.13.1 
Keras-Applications            1.0.8  
Keras-Preprocessing           1.1.0  
kiwisolver                    1.1.0  
laser-geometry                1.6.4  
Markdown                      3.1.1  
matplotlib                    3.1.1  
message-filters               1.14.3 
numpy                         1.17.3 
Pillow                        6.2.1  
pip                           19.0.3 
protobuf                      3.10.0 
pyparsing                     2.4.4  
python-dateutil               2.8.1  
python-qt-binding             0.3.6  
qt-dotgraph                   0.3.15 
qt-gui                        0.3.15 
qt-gui-cpp                    0.3.15 
qt-gui-py-common              0.3.15 
resource-retriever            1.12.5 
rosbag                        1.14.3 
rosboost-cfg                  1.14.7 
rosclean                      1.14.7 
roscreate                     1.14.7 
rosgraph                      1.14.3 
roslaunch                     1.14.3 
roslib                        1.14.7 
roslint                       0.11.2 
roslz4                        1.14.3 
rosmake                       1.14.7 
rosmaster                     1.14.3 
rosmsg                        1.14.3 
rosnode                       1.14.3 
rosparam                      1.14.3 
rospy                         1.14.3 
rosservice                    1.14.3 
rostest                       1.14.3 
rostopic                      1.14.3 
rosunit                       1.14.7 
roswtf                        1.14.3 
rqt-action                    0.4.9  
rqt-bag                       0.4.12 
rqt-bag-plugins               0.4.12 
rqt-console                   0.4.8  
rqt-dep                       0.4.9  
rqt-graph                     0.4.10 
rqt-gui                       0.5.0  
rqt-gui-py                    0.5.0  
rqt-image-view                0.4.13 
rqt-launch                    0.4.8  
rqt-logger-level              0.4.8  
rqt-moveit                    0.5.7  
rqt-msg                       0.4.8  
rqt-nav-view                  0.5.7  
rqt-plot                      0.4.9  
rqt-pose-view                 0.5.8  
rqt-publisher                 0.4.8  
rqt-py-common                 0.5.0  
rqt-py-console                0.4.8  
rqt-reconfigure               0.5.0  
rqt-robot-dashboard           0.5.7  
rqt-robot-monitor             0.5.9  
rqt-robot-steering            0.5.9  
rqt-runtime-monitor           0.5.7  
rqt-rviz                      0.6.0  
rqt-service-caller            0.4.8  
rqt-shell                     0.4.9  
rqt-srv                       0.4.8  
rqt-tf-tree                   0.6.0  
rqt-top                       0.4.8  
rqt-topic                     0.4.10 
rqt-web                       0.4.8  
rviz                          1.13.5 
sensor-msgs                   1.12.7 
setuptools                    41.6.0 
six                           1.13.0 
smach                         2.0.1  
smach-ros                     2.0.1  
smclib                        1.8.3  
tensorboard                   1.14.0 
tensorflow                    1.14.0 
tensorflow-estimator          1.14.0 
termcolor                     1.1.0  
tf                            1.12.0 
tf-conversions                1.12.0 
tf2-geometry-msgs             0.6.5  
tf2-kdl                       0.6.5  
tf2-py                        0.6.5  
tf2-ros                       0.6.5  
tf2-sensor-msgs               0.6.5  
topic-tools                   1.14.3 
unique-id                     1.0.6  
urdfdom-py                    0.4.1  
Werkzeug                      0.16.0 
wheel                         0.33.6 
wrapt                         1.11.2 
xacro                         1.13.4
```

Comment: Were the contents of logdir created with TensorFlow 2.0 or 1.14? I would not expect TensorBoard 1.14 to be able read the log files created with TensorFlow 2.0.

Comment: Also having both tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu (in the 1.14.0) environment installed at the same time looks wrong to me.

Comment: thanks for the commit of @ WilliamD.Irons,I have tried to uninstall the tensorflow-gpu in a new venv. I think the version of tensorflow produced the log is 1.14, or at least 1.x